# How do I get hair strands to curve in blender?

Tags: particles

[image: Hair Stands will not curve]

How do I get the hair strands in blender to curve? I tried the forcefield but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try increasing the number of segments. In my image that setting is greyed out, because I've done some particle edit after setting it. It needs to be set before editing the hair. 50 segments, like I have here, is overkill, I just set it to something high.
[image]

Lowering the Degrees setting under Render in the Particle settings may also help. To access that setting you'll need to activate Strand render.
You could also fiddle with the B-spline setting, but increasing the number of steps will slow things down.
[image]

Here are some settings I've just played with. The ones under Hair dynamics affect how fast and how far the hairs will fall.
[image]

And this is what I put together using those settings
[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping, but the main hairs are still not curving.. The black hair in my picture still look the same after adding like 45 segments.. Any suggestions????

Comment: @KeshaWilson Hm. Try lowering the degrees setting under "Render" in the particle settings. Its help text says "How many degrees path has to curve to make another render segment." You have to enable Strand render for that setting to be available.

Comment: Another thing you may need to increase is the "Path steps" under Tool shelf > Tools > Options > Draw.